# Parent page showing content from child page instead

Tags: channel-entries, structure, pages

I am using Structure to create and order the pages.

I am having an issue where the parent page is displaying the data of the child page instead of it's own data.

All 3 pages uses the same channel.

```
Parent
 - Child 1
 - Child 2
```

Eg instead of displaying the title `Parent` it is displaying `child 2`

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="page" dynamic="off" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1"}
   {title}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add url_title, Structure places the right data for you.